# Speedup IONIC 2 App Load Time or Splash Screen Delay For Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, splash-screen

I have created one Ionic 2 App and everything is almost fine. problem is when I open app in IOS it loads quickly after 2/3 secs holding the Splash screen but when it comes to android splash screen shows up to 7 to 10 secs before the home screen appears.

I searched many on speed up but no perfect solution or explanation found on this. Majority of answer says to assign 3 secs value for SplashScreenDelay in config.xml but it did not make any change.

Please let me know if there is any way to get it working.

Thanks

Comment: Run with the --prod flag and check if there's any change in app load time

Comment: I already tried with debug, unsigned and signed apks, it is same for all..

Comment: I have the same problem in my app, and I cannot find any reason why app load is very slow on android

Comment: Just check at what point you are setting your page to appear in app.component. Try setting the page (or in case some page or modal temporarily) at the start of the constructor till the operation completes. Then set the required page. I think there will be some delay which you cannot control when app loads. It is best to use splash screen. To be frank this also depends on the phone's performance as well. I have tried on both low and high performing phones. It matters. There will be difference from 5-7 seconds in these.

Comment: Also, use `<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />` may be to have a good look-n-feel indicating app is loading.

Comment: Make sure you are using the  --prod flag as @AldrinMathew mention and to have the latest version from ionic-cli and @ionic/app-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the SplashScreenDelay you can manually close the plugin when you know the app is ready:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

on config.xml

```
initializeApp() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {


        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        this.splashscreen.hide();

    });

}
```

on app.component.ts to

Comment: Thanks for you answer but just checked with mine and can see already the both has been applied in my config.xml & app.comoponent.ts